# Why must I reload ArduinoCreateAgent-1.1-windows-installer-chrome every time I restart my computer?

Tags: arduino-uno

What am I missing that this is happening?
Used to use a laptop (with Create Agent installed on hard drive) which never had this problem.
Now using a Windows 10 desktop and the On-line Create Agent.
Unless I reload the Arduino Create Agent, I always get the 'No Plug-In Connection' error message, please see screen capture. [image] Device manager recognizes the Arduino Uno and assigns COM3 to the USB connection, please see screen capture.[image: Screen Capture from Device Manager]

Comment: what do you mean by `reload the Arduino Create Agent` ... do you mean that you have to refresh the webpage?

Comment: @jsotola, Agent is the locally installed part of the Web IDE. the installation sets it to start automatically at logon. it looks like this failed

Comment: Yes, I mean that I have to refresh the Arduino Create Editor each time the computer is rebooted.  Logging onto the computer or into the Arduino WEB IDE does not automatically refresh the Create Agent.  What would cause this to fail the refresh? How can I correct this issue? I am pretty computer savvy but this one is escaping me!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all who have suggested corrective action for my posted communication problem.  After trying all of the suggestions, I threw up my hands and deleted all evidence of Arduino Create Editor.  Next I installed the Arduino Create Editor as a fresh/new install.  Magically, all of my communication issues with the Arduino Uno have been corrected.  Apparently, something in the communication code was corrupted during my first attempt install on my desktop PC.